# Convert FLV to MP4 video files on MAC OSx

Tags: cocoa, video, applescript, quicktime, qtkit

I am newbie on Mac OSx. I want to convert videos from one format to another like MP4 to MOV, FLV to MP4, MP4 to 3GP etc. I have already surfed on net. I found cocoa can do something using its QTKit architecture. In this, we can export videos in different formats. but i am not able to check that is it useful for FLV format. I want to convert FLV to MP4. Am I on right way or is there any other way for this conversion of videos.Your any kind of help will really appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at ffmpeg: http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Thanks for your response Merlin, but i don't want to use ffmpeg. Is there any other way for the same ?

Comment: Well, you could research the algorithms for each format and write your own, but why not use ffmpeg, which is tried and tested?

Comment: I am creating this application for distribution purpose but ffmpeg comes under GPL/LGPL license terms which says that if i use ffmpeg in my application then i have to distribute my object files too that i can't. so any other suggestion please :-( . Thanks.

Comment: I would look to factor out the video conversion part of your application to another application which you release under the same licence. That way the main application can stay proprietary and just call the helper application when required.

Comment: hey merlin..i think you are right...Can i compile ffmpeg with different name on MAC OS..?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: thanks for your reply merlin..Can you help me in this..or ..do you have any documentation for compiling the new build ..?

Comment: If you're not sure what to do and have researched the problem, I suggest asking a new question on SO. That will give greater visibility in the community and will likely produce the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

FLV is probably the simplest video container in existence, Just download the spec (Adobe Flash Video File Format Specification Version 10.1), and parse it manually. Then use QTKit, or another third party library to remux to mp4.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to convert video formats using MacOSX command line (any version). First download this compressed file and unpack it to your Movies Folder:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3NlLwMD4yd9QU0yVGJyU1NiUDA/view?usp=sharing

You will then have a MMedia_Converter directory with two apps: MMedia_Convert and Android_Converter. Those are my own developed MacOSX open source applications, bassed on FFMpeg Group and HandBrake Group France previous work. Both are fully compliant Mac compilled applications and you´ll have have to do nothing but extract them to your Movies Folder.

You also have there, 3 folders: clip_in, clip_out and scripts.

You must put the videos you want to be converted in the clip_in folder.

The converted output videos, will be generated automatically in the clip_out folder.

In addition you have 2 bash scripts, that you must move to your Mac OSX Desktop.

Once these bash are on desktop, edit them with TextEdit, and change my user name by your Mac name.

In my case, I use one script to generate thumbnails and the other to generate thumbnails too, and to automatically convert videos from any formar to wathever I choose.

"Whatever" means, that if you want to convert mpeg to mkv, you will have to declare it in line: DEST_EXT=mkv (or wathever known video format you want).

Hope this will help you all.

Best Regards, Tomás Hernández